# How to implement a map of lazy values in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a bunch of lookup tables indexed by `key` that I would like instantiate lazily (i.e. the tables are expensive to compute and I only expect *some* of them to be used on any given execution of the code).

```
private var myLazyMap: Map<KeyClass, TableClass> by lazy { ...}
```

Doesn't work as that makes the map object itself lazy, which isn't right. I think I may need to write a custom delegate, but I still can't see how to embed that into the map object.

I *could* wrap `TableClass` with something like

```
class LazyTable(val param: TableClassParameter) {
   private var table: TableClass by lazy { TableClass(param) }

   fun wrappedTableFun(): ResultClass {
     return table.tableFun()
   }
}
```

But this does mean the class is wrong and it feels like a hack. Can this be done in a neater way?

Comment: How do you enter values to the map?

Comment: Shouldn't you write your own `LazyMap`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be implemented in multiple ways, depending on your needs. Probably the easiest is to use a map of lazy values directly:

```kotlin
val map = mutableMapOf<KeyClass, Lazy<TableClass>>()

map[myKey1] = lazy { createTable1() }
map[myKey2] = lazy { createTable2() }

val table = map[myKey1]?.value
```

If we want to not expose `Lazy` to the users of the map, we need to create our own `LazyMap`. One way is to use a map similar to above and just hide `Lazy` from the user:

```kotlin
class LazyMap<K, V>(
    private val map: Map<K, Lazy<V>>
) {
    operator fun get(key: K): V? = map[key]?.value
}
```

Another solution is to use a function that creates values when needed:

```kotlin
class LazyMap<K, V>(
    private val compute: (K) -> V
) {
    private val map = mutableMapOf<K, V>()

    operator fun get(key: K): V? = map.getOrPut(key) { compute(key) }
}
```

We can also use a separate `compute` function per each key, as in the answer by @tibtof .

Comment: Thanks. Embarrassingly, overloading Map failed to occur to me.

Answer (score 4):

A partial implementation could be something like this:

```
class LazyMap<K, V>(val lazyVals: Map<K, () -> V>, val cache: MutableMap<K, V> = mutableMapOf()) : Map<K, V> by cache {

    companion object {
        fun <K, V> lazyMapOf(vararg entries: Pair<K, () -> V>): LazyMap<K, V> = LazyMap(mapOf(*entries))
    }

    override fun get(key: K): V? = cache[key] ?: lazyVals[key]?.let { cache[key] = it(); cache[key] }
}

fun main() {
    val lazyMap = lazyMapOf(
        1 to { println("computing one"); "one" },
        2 to { println("computing two"); "two" }
    )

    println("get 2")
    println(lazyMap[2])
    println("get 1")
    println(lazyMap[1])
    println("get 0")
    println(lazyMap[0])
    println("get 2 again")
    println(lazyMap[2])
}
```

An we can observe the lazyness in the output:

```
get 2
computing two
two
get 1
computing one
one
get 0
null
get 2 again
two
```

Comment: Note that this solution isn't thread safe, if you use this map from multiple threads you need to implement get in an atomic way. e.g. use a `ConcurrentHashMap` as delegate instead of a generic `MutableMap`

Comment: `V` should be `V: Any` as this cannot handle nullable `V`.